# '"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, git-bash, npx

[Why I'm getting this error. I'm not even running node command '"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
I tried this command->
npx create-react-app amazon-clone]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should install nodejs first. Start from [here](https://nodejs.org/)

Comment: Its already installed and working fine. I'm just new to react world and I have to run                    
    " npx create-react-app . " command for which I first installed it globally using  npm install -g create-react-app   and now I,m getting this error- '“node”' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: What is your OS and shell type?

Comment: OS-windows  I generally use Git Bash

Comment: Have you tried `node -v` in your Git Bash shell - if it gives you similar results, your Bash shell may not have a path set to the location of the `node` binary. Also, try the `node -v` command from a Windows `cmd` shell or from a Windows Terminal session to confirm if you do have node correctly installed.